# Amazon AWS volume full although www folder has 88 megs

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

my mysql failed because, apparently, my volume is filled. All 8 gb of it. I only have put mongodb, nodejs, apache, mysql and in the www folder, wordpress and phpmyadmin.

My question is, what happened and how do I fix it?

Here is what df -h gave me:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1            7.9G  7.9G     0 100% /
tmpfs                 298M     0  298M   0% /dev/shm
```

Comment: `sudo du -hs /*` will help you start narrowing down what's causing it.

Comment: @ceejayoz how do I do this within a directory? I want to narrow down directories

Comment: `sudo du -hs /directory/*`

Comment: look at my answer..... you can narrow down further even by executing "du -xk / |sort -n"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i personally like "du -xk / |sort -n"  as that will list the largest/top used directories on and only the root partition.

that said, root partition is not for storing data.  being you are on aws, it is very easy to simply mount another volume whereever you need it

EDIT:

> 1) ec2-create-volume
>   2) ec2-attach-volume
>   3) fixup /etc/fstab
>   4) mount /path/to/mountpoint